# Android app doesn't open required activity instead it opens other

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Help me out friends I have been facing a problem from a week
I have made an android app in which I got 3 activities named

```
MainActivity
NotificationListActivity
NotificationActivity
```

other than that I have 2 services in my app ( as because I am using FCM )

```
JLZFirebaseMsgService
JLZInstanceIdService
```

in JLZFirebaseMsgService.java I have written the code

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotificationActivity.class);
//        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Jee Lo Zindagi 2.0")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

what I want is to whenever FCM server sends the notification to the devices the app should open NotificationActivity as the I wrote

but whenever I tap on the notification it opens the MainActivity I don't know why.

when the app is open the notification comes and by tapping on it we go to the NotificationActivity that's what I wanted but not the same scenario when the app is closed.

but sometimes it happens that the app shows the correct activity by tapping on the notification I still don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "data" insted of "notification" on your server code 
When you use "notification" on your server code
 while you app is not running the JLZFirebaseMsgService.java does not start . instead the you will recevie a notification with your launcher icon
But if you use "data" on your server code your messaging service will start

Comment: I have written a Nodejs app for it to send notification, you can check it out.



    var message = { 
        to: '/topics/jlz', 
        collapse_key: 'your_collapse_key', 
        data: {
            hasNotification: "true",
            notifTitle : notificationTitle,
            notifMsg : notificationMessage,
            notifDate : mdate
        },
        notification: {
            title: notificationTitle,
            message: notificationMessage
        }
    };

Comment: You may try delete the notification part keep the data only

Comment: var message = { to: '/topics/jlz', collapse_key: 'your_collapse_key', data: { hasNotification: "false", notifTitle : notificationTitle, notifMsg : notificationMessage, notifDate : mdate }}

Comment: let me give it a try..... can you add me on facebook u can search me through ( sarosh madara )

Comment: can we have a conversation?

Comment: Sure dear , I have sent you a friend request on fb

Comment: I tried it the outcome is when notification comes it says unfortunately, app has stopped

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are sending a notification messages, these are messages that go to onMessageReceived when your app is in the foreground in your case that will result in you manually generating a notification, when your app is in the background it will result in an auto-generated notification that your code does not define.

If you are using the FCM REST API then you can use the [click_action](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) field which would allow you to define which activity would be launched when the user taps on the notification. If you are using the Firebase console there currently you cannot specify a click_action from there.